# Integration of Microsoft's FLUID Framework for iOS native app development?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, real-time, fluid-framework

I am asked to implement Microsoft's FLUID framework integration with my existing iOS application developed in Swift (xcode), to achieve realtime data in our application. I have googled around but didn't find any single topic about it. Is there any way to achieve this?